# Stata automatically tests collinearity for logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, stata, multicollinearity

I'm using Stata for logistic regression. This software automatically checks for collinearity and remove (drop) some variables as we can see below:

```
. logit I A B C D XX

note: XX omitted because of collinearity
Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -289.73552  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -230.69547  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -203.22756  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -198.37658  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -198.27812  
Iteration 5:   log likelihood = -198.27791  
Iteration 6:   log likelihood = -198.27791  

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =        418
                                                LR chi2(4)        =     182.92
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -198.27791                     Pseudo R2         =     0.3157

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           I |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           A |   8.694651   1.250269     6.95   0.000     6.244168    11.14513
           B |  -1.384168   .5934295    -2.33   0.020    -2.547269    -.221068
           C |   .1348553   .1269632     1.06   0.288    -.1139881    .3836986
           D |  -.2188249   .1664487    -1.31   0.189    -.5450583    .1074085
          XX |          0  (omitted)
       _cons |   1.956985   .3378121     5.79   0.000     1.294886    2.619085
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: 0 failures and 14 successes completely determined.
```

I think Stata only checks for perfect linear relationship between independent variables (100% correlation). Is this true?

If the answer to that question is yes, is this true based on theoretical framework? We should only consider perfect collinearity?

Comment: Despite the total focus on Stata, there is a statistical question here. In return: what is your idea of imperfect collinearity that Stata might use to vet predictors? If any correlation between predictors is suspect, no statistical software would be any use for anything but single-predictor models.

Comment: Stata terminology: best not to say that Stata drops variables, as the word is used for the `drop` command which removes data from the dataset in memory. The word used in the output is much better: Stata omits (= does not use) certain variables, their coefficients being returned as 0.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So Stata only check extreme situation (perfect collinearity) as default? Is this sufficient in real models? I'm comparing 98% correlation between two variables and 100%. Stata only consider perfect linear and there isn't any boundary here. Is this statistically true?

Comment: Suppose that I'm working on a paper. Can I use only Stata procedure for collinearity?

Comment: Note that correlations are best not reported as percents. I am not going to try to answer fully on Stata's behalf here, not least because the details of particular software are off-topic here. I am trying to get you to pose a sharp statistical question and I can't see one yet. What does "statistically true" mean? Why should "working on a paper" be pertinent here? If you have a problematic model, then you need to experiment with including and excluding particular predictors, and you can always check to see whether some different software agrees.

Comment: That's true but suppose that in variable correlation plots we have high correlation of 0.98 between two independent variables. We should consider this high correlation in our model designing(or consider only perfect collinearity)?

Comment: Again, I am not sure what you are asking, but typically if you know that two predictors are correlated at 0.98 then it's usually a bad idea to include both in a model. You shouldn't leave it to Stata to tell you that is a bad idea. But much depends on context. For example, there can be good reasons to include $x$ and $x^2$ in a model and their correlation could be very high. See also `[R] estimation options` on `collinear` in the Stata documentation.

Comment: I'm offended by the repeated appearances of the word "adult" in the answers, given the OP's question does not demonstrate any trait of being childish or throwing a temper tantrum. Knowing how to operate a software or master a technique has nothing to do with age or maturity. "Independent and well-informed user" maybe, "adult" probably not necessary.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I have known both people who have answered so far for several years and I know them quite well. I feel confident that the word "adult" is not intended offensively at all. On the contrary, the intended sense is that Stata pays you a compliment in expecting that you are happy to take on the responsibility for modelling choices such as selection of predictors. So "adult" is meant positively without any contrast with "childish" at all.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for stepping in. I don't have the privilege of knowing the posters personally but I have been respecting their contributions and believe the intention is not of negative nature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not you want to omit a variable (or do something else) when the correlation is very high but not perfect is a choice. Stata treats its users as adults and lets you make your own choices. With perfect collinearity there is no choice: there is no information present in the data that allows Stata to separate the two effects. It could return an error message and not estimate the model, or Stata can chose one of the offending variables to omit. StataCorp chose the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment:

As a side note, I find the coefficient of `8.69` of the `A` variable to be bizarrely high. If it were a 0/1 variable, then it would imply `~exp(8.69)=5943` difference in incidence of `I` in the two categories of `A`, but you only have 418 cases, so the difference in rates cannot realistically be more than 1:418 or so. More likely, `A` is a continuous variable with little variability. At any rate, as you seem to be running into computational issues, rescaling `A` to have approximately unit variance may help. Even though Stata is very, very good in computational issues, as @MaartenBuis [put it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158445/5739), you need to be an adult in working with it and help it out if you can. It may also be that either `A` or `XX` is causing the perfect prediction that Stata mentions.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I standardized every independent variable using `abs(X-mean(X))/STD(X)`. So here we are talking about effect of one standard deviation change on dependent variable. What do you think about this structure? We have correct results in this framework?

Comment: Can you plot `lowess I A` and `lowess I XX` to see how these variables are related? I continue to think there's something weird about them.

Comment: @user2991243 `abs(X-mean(X))/STD(X)`?? Not sure what the `abs()` is doing there, but it ensures that your "standardized" variable is not centered on 0, and is not centered on some standard quantity. It also does not ensure the variance of the "standardized" variable is 1. Don't you instead want [`(X - mean(X))/STD(X)`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/z-score/info)?

Answer (score 0):

Using correlation between predictors is not nearly as informative as the variance inflation factors (VIFs) or the condition number (ratio of largest to smallest eigenvalue, $\sqrt{\lambda_{\max}/\lambda_{\min}})$ of the inverted Hessian matrix, $(\mathbf{X}^{\textsf{T}}\mathbf{X})^{-1}$ or $\left[\partial^2 \cal{l}(\boldsymbol{\beta})/\partial \beta_j \partial \beta_k \right]^{-1}$), to determine whether multicollinearity is present among predictors.  **(Yes, VIFs can be run for predictors of logistic regression, since they're derived from regressing each predictor on the remaining predictors -- has nothing to do with the dependent variable)**.

I have seen very bad ill-conditioned logistic regression models with between-predictor correlation of $|r|<0.5$, i.e., not perfect ($|r|=1$), with VIFs $\gg10$  - indicating severe multicollinearity.  Thus, hunting down perfect correlation ($|r|=1)$ won't help because extreme multicollinarity can occur with $|r|<0.5$.   You need to determine VIFs or look at the condition number of the inverted Hessian.